# MySql - Подсчет накопительной суммы с сортировкой по дате

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица:

```
id | type | amount  |   date
---+------+---------+----------
1     1      50.00   01.10.2021
2     1     100.00   01.12.2021
3     1     150.00   01.11.2021

SELECT `id`, `amount`, @total:=@total + `amount` AS total, `date` 
FROM ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM `operations` 
    WHERE `type` = 1
    ORDER BY `date`
) AS data_table
JOIN (SELECT @total:=0) st 
WHERE @total < 10000
```

Выводит:

```
id | amount |  total  |   date
---+--------+---------+----------
1     50.00     50.00   01.10.2021
2     100.00   150.00   01.12.2021
3     150.00   300.00   01.11.2021
```

Ожидается вывод:

```
id | amount |  total  |   date
---+--------+---------+----------
1     50.00     50.00   01.10.2021
3     150.00   200.00   01.11.2021
2     100.00   300.00   01.12.2021
```

т.е. не происходит сортировка по дате. По задумке должно было выбрать таблицу (data_table) отсортированную по дате, затем пройтись по ней и подсчитать накопительную сумму.
Как его заставить считать по отсортированным данным?

Вариант @Akina (запрос и вывод):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT `id`, `amount`, @total:=@total + `amount` AS total, `date` 
       FROM `operations` 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @total:=0) variable
       WHERE `type` = 1
       ORDER BY `date` ) subquery
WHERE total < 10000

id | amount |  total  |   date
---+--------+---------+----------
1     50.00     50.00   01.10.2021
3     150.00   300.00   01.11.2021
2     100.00   150.00   01.12.2021
```

Даты отсортировало, но `total` не нарастающий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT `id`, `amount`, @total:=@total + `amount` AS total, `date` 
       FROM `operations` 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @total:=0) variable
       WHERE `type` = 1
       ORDER BY `date` ) subquery
WHERE total < 10000
```

1. ORDER BY подзапроса всегда игнорируется во внешнем запросе.
2. ORDER BY  обязан присутствовать именно в запросе, работающем с переменными, чтобы обеспечить правильный порядок обработки.
3. Проверка значения поля, вычисляемого с использованием переменной, должна выполняться после формирования всего набора записей. Иначе планировщик обработает значение как константу, полученную из подзапроса, инициализирующего переменную.

---

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d835c32c7a3267656f371d2440297c1e)

Comment: не сработало - сортировка как и ожидается произвелась последней

Comment: @Alex Не верю. PS. Добавлен DEMO fiddle.

Comment: да, все работает. Это у меня локально почему-то не срабатывала сортировка. Не пойму почему, но на хостинге все работает

Comment: @Alex *Это у меня локально почему-то не срабатывала сортировка.* Навскидку могут предположить только одну причину - инициализация переменной выполнялась не в подзапросе, а извне, заранее...